# How to pause timer from appdelegate in xcode and objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am making a game for iPhone and want to be able to pause a timer when a user's game is interrupted like when they hit the home button. I know that in the app delegate there is a method when the app leaves the foreground called:

```
    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

What I am struggling with is how to pause the timer. I have a function in my view controller that's called pauseGame and is used for when the user wants to pause the game. I was thinking that it would be easiest to pause the game by using this method. I cannot however understand how to call this method. Any ideas? And sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: Is it a count-down timer (time remaining) or a count-up timer (time elapsed)?  Do you decrement/increment the timer in your game update method, or do you just calculate time remaining/elapsed from a base time that you don't modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest way is to Use Notifications:

**1.** define a custom notification, at your application delegate (or anywhere else...)

```
#define kApplicationWillResignActiveNotification  
@"kApplicationWillResignActiveNotification"
```

**2.** dispatch the notification when the applicationWillResignActive: method is called

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
kApplicationWillResignActive object:nil];
```

**3.** listen to that notification where ever you want in your project (* import the header file where you @defined the notification)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector: @selector(appResigned:) 
name:kApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object: nil];
```

**4.** you can get the NSNotification Object if you add it to your selector

```
-(void)appResigned:(NSNotification *)notification;
```